# How to define type to allow null in createContext React TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have issue about typescript when creating modal context with typescript, I want to null as default value in createContext but it will causing typescript error

```
import React from 'react';

type TModal = boolean;
type TModalContext = [TModal, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<TModal>>];

const ModalContext = React.createContext<TModalContext | null>(null); // allow null as defaut value

const ModalProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const modalState = useState<TModal>(false);

    return <ModalContext.Provider value={modalState}>{children}</ModalContext.Provider>;
};

const useModalContext = () => React.useContext(ModalContext);
```

When I call useModalContext hook to use in another component I get an error:

> Type 'TModalContext | null' is not an array type.ts(2461)

```
const [isOpen, setOpen] = useModalContext();
```

How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1:

Because you tell the compile that `null` is a valid value, the most simple way is throw an `Error` when the context is `null`:

```
const useModalContext = () => {
    const context = React.useContext(ModalContext);
    if(context === null) throw new Error; // or do other things here
    return context
}
```

You won't to worry about the app crashed by the `Error` if you always call the hook inside the context

### Solution 2:

On the other hand, if you can't ensure the hook is always safe, you should consider handle the `null` value from the caller:

```
const context = useModalContext();
const [isOpen, setOpen] = context ?? []
```